# Display svg image as node of d3.js in phonejs

Tags: d3.js, phonejs

Making application with phonejs, using d3.js with force layout. I want to display images as node of d3.

Here is how node is created:

```
node = container.append("g").selectAll("image.node")
    .data(nodes_edges_json.nodes)
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(nodeObj) { return nodeObj.image; })
    .attr("width", function(nodeObj) { return setHeightWidth(nodeObj); })
    .attr("height", function(nodeObj) { return setHeightWidth(nodeObj); })
    .attr("x", function(nodeObj) { return setXYCoordinates("x", nodeObj); })
    .attr("y", function(nodeObj) { return setXYCoordinates("y", nodeObj); })
    .attr("title",function(nodeObj) { return nodeObj.name;})
    .call(drag);
```

Currently it does not display images in place of nodes.

Comment: What does it display? Are the image URLs correct? See e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642).

Comment: URLs are coorect...the problem is it does not display images when I try it on mobile phone..@Lars Katthoff

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add an enter()

```
node = container.append("g").selectAll("image.node")
.data(nodes_edges_json.nodes).enter() //  <-----------------HERE
.append("svg:image")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("xlink:href", function(nodeObj) { return nodeObj.image; })
.attr("width", function(nodeObj) { return setHeightWidth(nodeObj); })
.attr("height", function(nodeObj) { return setHeightWidth(nodeObj); })
.attr("x", function(nodeObj) { return setXYCoordinates("x", nodeObj); })
.attr("y", function(nodeObj) { return setXYCoordinates("y", nodeObj); })
.attr("title",function(nodeObj) { return nodeObj.name;})
.call(drag);
```

Comment: Yea it works fine when I test it on browser but it doesn't display images when I try it on mobile phone.. @GingerJim